# Prayer before a general anaesthetic

Tags: tefilla, minhag, blessing, medicine

Every night, prior to bed, people recite the Shema. Affixed to that recitation is a variety of psukim and brokhes, requesting of Hashem that He ensure that we will sleep well, without any disturbance, and that we will awaken in the morning. Is there anything of a similar nature (without the Shema, of course) that can be recited before a general anaesthetic?

Comment: "can" or "should"? Any of the customary pre-bed verses, including shema, _can_ be recited before an anesthetic, or in fact whenever one's fancy is so struck.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I just didn't want to ask my question as though I were soliciting a psak. I am happy to edit it if doing so won't cause me to fall afoul of the site's rules.